# tmux hightlight colour setting

Tags: tmux, colors

In `tmux`, the default highlight setting is a yellow background -- at least on my version and machine. This is when using the mouse on X11 but is the same with the console selection. I cannot find the option to change this in the man page.

What is the option to change this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The option you're looking for is called `mode-style`.

For example, entering `:set mode-style "fg=red,bg=blue"` in the `tmux` command prompt and selecting something from `man tmux` yields the following result:

[image: tmux mode-style demo screenshot]

Note that this option also affects the display of the line counter (here `[0/11]`) in the upper right corner of the pane in copy-mode.

Comment: I probably should have said that this option is for both, mouse and console selections. It also changes the color in the selection of windows dialog via `C-b s` and maybe some other things.

Comment: is it possible to make colors to be reverted as in vim visual mode?

Comment: I came here wanting the currently selected search instance, which I have found is `copy-mode-current-match-style`.